# Detect user opens the keypad

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I wants to check that if user open the keypad then i wants to show a alertbox. How can i do this? if background service is required than can anyone tell me how to detect user opens the keypad.

I want to detect with normal use of phone.like if user open keypad to call then one alert box shows.

Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Comment: @flx I want to detect with normal use of phone.like if user open keypad to call then one alert box shows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
try {
        activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                Rect r = new Rect();
                getScreenRootView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);


                int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
                if (heightDiff > 100) {
                    // keypad is open
                } 
            }
        });
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: In your activity's onResume() method